# Is there a way to get all records where action_text is nill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, actiontext

my model looks like

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :profile_text
end
```

Now I am trying to find all the records that have an empty `profile_text`

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look at the action-text table

```rb
 create_table :action_text_rich_texts do |t|
    t.string     :name, null: false
    t.text       :body, size: :long
    t.references :record, null: false, polymorphic: true, index: false

    t.timestamps

    t.index [ :record_type, :record_id, :name ], 
     name: "index_action_text_rich_texts_uniqueness", 
     unique: true
 end
```

in which, `name` is corresponding to the rich-text attribute (in your case, it's `profile_text`), `record`(type and id) are corresponding to your class `User`.

So in my opinion, one way to go is to pluck `record_id`s from all action-text which has body present, and the complement records which not in  this `record_id`s are corresponding to records (empty or nil) you want to query.

```rb
  scope :without_rich_text, -> {
    ids = ActionText::RichText
      .where(name: 'profile_text', record_type: 'User')
      .where.not(body: [nil, ""])
      .pluck(:record_id)

    where.not(id: ids)
  }

 User.without_rich_text
 User.without_rich_text.first
 User.where(department: [1,2,3]).without_rich_text
```

Note that iam trying to cover the case there're users in which `profile_text` is not existed in the `action-text` table at all, so i query with negative case `where.not`.

if you're sure that all your User `profile_text` existed in the `action-text` table and you just want to filter all empty records, then you could query with positive case

```rb
  scope :without_rich_text, -> {
    ids = ActionText::RichText
      .where(name: 'profile_text', record_type: 'User')
      .where(body: [nil, ""])
      .pluck(:record_id)

    where(id: ids)
  }
```